# Trouble reading timestamp when loading from text file

Tags: postgresql, copy

I'm an Oracle user just starting to use PostgreSQL.  I'm having trouble reading a `timestamp` from the text file.

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE system_parameters
(
start_time      TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
)
;

COPY 
    system_parameters 
FROM 
    'Parameters.txt' 
;
```

The data in the file is
`10:00 PM`

I've seen suggestions about using SET datestyle but I haven't gotten that to work for me.  I've seen other suggestions about using AWK to rewrite the parameters.txt file and that could work but I'm guessing someone can help me get PostgreSQL to accept the data in its current format.

Answer (score 0):

To accept time in your time style column`start_time` type should be `time without time zone`

See an example

```
 create table sample_time 
 ( 
   times  time without time zone
 );

insert into sample_time values('12:25 AM');
insert into sample_time values('12:25 PM');
insert into sample_time values('10:00 PM');
insert into sample_time values('10:20 AM');
```

and this table contains data `select * from sample_time`

```
   times  
   time without time zone
   ---------------------
   00:25:00
   12:25:00
   22:00:00
   10:20:00
```

if you want to get the data in `AM/PM` style should use [TO_CHAR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
 select TO_CHAR(times, 'hh12:mi AM') from sample_time
```

so the result will be

```
   to_char
   text
   ---------
   12:25 AM
   12:25 PM
   10:00 PM
   10:20 AM
```

---

[***SQLFIDDLE DEMO***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0bc60/5)